# Use styler to replace T with TRUE, F with FALSE in R code

Tags: r

```r
library("styler")
myugly_code <- "if ( x==T ) print( 'y' )"
style_text(myugly_code)
#> if (x == T) print("y")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I acknowledge that we should always use `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of `T` and `F` in the first place when writing `R` code. However, when editing previous code or code written by others with `T` and `F`, is it possible to use packages like `styler` to replace all `T` and `F` with `TRUE` and `FALSE`. In the above code, I would like to get:

```
#> if (x == TRUE) print("y")
```

Comment: Unless it's well-hidden, I don't see it in the documentation. This is a nice idea, but could also be super-dangerous if someone happens to have used `T` as something other than a shortcut for `TRUE` ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks. Yes, I can see your point. I guess that's the reason to use `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the first place. It would be helpful with some warnings.

Comment: It would be fun to put this in your `.Rprofile`: `makeActiveBinding(quote(T), function() stop("don't use 'T' as a variable!"), .GlobalEnv)`. It wouldn't catch everything, but it would be a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about styler, but you can replace `'T'` with `'TRUE'` using `gsub`. The `'\\b'` character is a word boundary so that only a `'T'` with a word boundary on each side is replaced and not e.g. the `'T'` in `'Test'`.

```
sub_TF <- function(s){
  s <- gsub('\\bT\\b', 'TRUE', s)
  gsub('\\bF\\b', 'FALSE', s)
}

sub_TF("list(T, 'Test', F, 'Fox')")
# [1] "list(TRUE, 'Test', FALSE, 'Fox')"
```

Answer (score 1):

styler does not do that, because you can have

```r
T <- f(x)
T
```

Or assign really any value to `T`, so it's not safe to replace `T` in general. To detect the (mis)usage of `T` and `F`, use full text search or https://github.com/jimhester/lintr to detect it and resolve it manually.

You can find a discussion of the topic here: https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/3